# how to convert hexadecimal value expected output using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hex, data-conversion

I tried a lot of ways, but none give the expected result.

Input: `04:3d:54:a2:68:61:80`

Expected output: `01193333618139520`

How would I go about this in JS?

```js
const value = `04:3d:54:a2:68:61:80`
const barcode = parseInt(value.replace(':', ''), 16)
console.log(barcode) // 1085
```

Comment: please make an attempt and share [mcve] before asking for help.

Comment: [how-do-i-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-do-i-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript), also someone has to mention, that you are barely below `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, at 51 bits. If your input would start with `2` instead of `0`, that would already cause issues.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are using `replace` instead of `replaceAll`

```js
const value = `04:3d:54:a2:68:61:80`
const barcode = parseInt(value.replaceAll(':', ''), 16)
console.log(barcode)
```

As [Lian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4728913/lain) suggests, you can also achieve that with `replace(/:/g, '')`

And therefore get better [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#browser_compatibility)

```js
const value = `04:3d:54:a2:68:61:80`
const barcode = parseInt(value.replace(/:/g, ''), 16)
console.log(barcode)
```

Comment: For completeness and legacy sake: `.replace(/:/g, '')`

Answer (score 1):

First remove colons, then use parseInt(myHex, 16).

```html
const myHex = '04:3d:54:a2:68:61:80';

function hexToDecimal(hexadecimal) {
  return parseInt(hexadecimal.replaceAll(':', ''), 16);
}

console.log(hexToDecimal(myHex));
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function, passing your input as the first parameter and `16` (since hexadecimal is base-16) as the second.

```js
let input = '04:3d:54:a2:68:61:80';
const inputParsed = parseInt(input.replace(/:/g, ''), 16); // 1193333618139520
```

If you need the leading zero for some reason you can do something like this:

```js
const inputParsedStr = `${inputParsed.toString().startsWith('0') ? '' : '0'}${inputParsed}`; // '01193333618139520'
```